# Assign default value to a Many2one field for specific user group in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-9

I am assigning a `default value` to `analytic distribution` field in `account.invoice.line` by below code

```
        def _get_default_account(self, cr, uid, context=None):
            res = self.pool.get('account.analytic.plan.instance').search(cr, uid, [('code','=','LAL')], context=context)
            return res and res[0] or False

        _defaults = {
           'analytics_id': _get_default_account,
           }
```

but now i want to set default value for specific group of user. I want to set one value for a group and other value for other group. Means I want to set two different default values for different users.
Someone please give me some idea about it. I'll be very thankful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to approach that is using has_group method. You should do it like:

```
if self.env['res.users'].has_group('base.group1'):
    res = self.pool.get('account.analytic.plan.instance').search(cr, uid, [('code','=','LAL')], context=context)
    return res and res[0] or False
elif self.env['res.users'].has_group('base.group2'):
    res = self.pool.get('account.analytic.plan.instance').search(cr, uid, [('code','=','SAS')], context=context)
    return res and res[0] or False
```

And so on and so forth.

Comment: Sir it is giving me this error `AttributeError: 'account.invoice.line' object has no attribute 'env'`

Comment: thanks ***ariusz Mizgier*** i needed `self.pool['res.users'].has_group(cr, uid, 'base.group1')`

Comment: SIr it is working well for `account.invoice.line` but it doing nothing for `account.move.line`, can you please explain what is happening...???

Comment: If it works in one model, it works in all models - probably you have defined it wrong or an action you perform is done by SUPERUSER_ID.